# SUM with CASE.. Prevent divide by zero

Tags: sql, sum, case

My query:

```
SELECT 
UPC,
SUM(
        CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END
) /
SUM(
        CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_QUANTITY ELSE 0 END
)
```

Returns division by zero because if the upc has no data for `WEEK <= 13` then divisor will be zero.

I have this solution, but I need to create averages for multiple date ranges, and it seems a bit long.

```
SELECT
UPC,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN WEEKS <= 13 
    THEN Cost_Amount 
    ELSE 0 END
) /
CASE WHEN 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN WEEKS<=13 
        THEN Cost_Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END
    )=0 
THEN 1 
ELSE SUM(
        CASE WHEN WEEKS<=13 
        THEN Cost_Quantity 
        ELSE 0 END
    )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `else` in the denominator:

```
SELECT UPC,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_QUANTITY END)
       )
```

This will return `NULL` instead of an error.  You can use `COALESCE()` if you want to get a particular value in this case.

Comment: if i'm summing something i.e. 1,2,3,null,4,5, won't the whole thing equate to null?

Comment: @sk099 . . . No.  `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values, so your numbers will add up to 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can try breaking up the query a little -

```
SELECT 
    UPC, 
    SUM_COST_AMOUNT / DECODE(SUM_COST_QTY,0,1,SUM_COST_QTY)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        UPC,
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END
            ) AS SUM_COST_AMOUNT, 
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN WEEK <= 13 THEN COST_QUANTITY ELSE 0 END
            ) AS SUM_COST_QTY
    FROM .. 
    ..
    ..
    ..
)
```

Comment: We're talking Oracle here? If not a `DECODE()` might not help the OP.

Comment: Yes, this is specific to Oracle.